Bitbucket: Hide "import/package" changes in diff in pull request
I was wondering if there is a Bitbucket Plugin or something similar that detects import/package changes in a pull request and either hides those lines or if the file is only consisting of these changes, collapses the file. If not I'm probably going to try to build a plugin that does that, is that possible?

Are you asking about Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or a self-hosted one? (They share a name, and a basic function, and that's about it.)

Are you sure that you (and the developers) really want it? Also, if there are multiple imports from the same package and their number exceeds a certain threshold, the IDEs are typically configured to automatically squash them into one .* import.

@JimRedmond bitbucket.org is what I meant, yes

@AlexanderPletnev I think ktlint (our linter) doesnt really like wildcard imports. its just really a pain if there are a lot of files to review, but most of the changed lines are just import changes e.g.

There are cases where reviewing the actual packages is crucial - for example, when importing annotations that have the same name but can behave differently (like @Test or other ones from JUnit 4 and JUnit5)

@AlexanderPletnev well for most of our cases its not that interesting, thats why I want to hide it
